# Why is BeautifulSoup extracting unreferenced tags?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<div id="reply" class="reply attachment text">
    <p class="intro">
        <label for="delete">
            <span class="name">Name</span>
        </label>

        <span class="identification">0123456789</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

With the above html I want to get the id number '0123456789'.

To get the id I tried:

```
ids = soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'span' and tag.findParent('p', 'intro') and tag.findParent('p', 'intro').findParent('div', class_=re.compile("(.)*attachment(.)*$")))
```

and

```
ids = soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.findChild('p', 'intro') and tag.findChild('p', 'intro').findChild('span', class_='poster_id'))
```

but every time I get (with .get_Text()):

```
#by John Smith
#0123456789
```

'recursive=False' gives no output

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with this class `identification`? Did you try using it directly?

Comment: @SIM I used it in the second example = "poster_id". My typo, sorry

Comment: Try this `ids = soup.select_one("#reply .identification").text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div id="reply" class="reply attachment text">
<p class="intro">
    <label for="delete">
        <span class="name">Name</span>
    </label>

    <span class="identification">0123456789</span>
</p>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
content = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'identification')
print(content[0].get_text())

#o/p
'0123456789'
```

Comment: Ah. Simple and functional. Cheers qaiser.